# I just started learning Vue Js, I am trying to click on a button then the button will be disabled, its not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<button :disabled="false" @click="whenclick">TEST</button>

methods: {
    whenclick(){
    this.disabled=true;
    },
},
```

and can anyone give me tips on how to learn vuejs, im trying to learn from laracasts atm, i am learning vue js to use it with laravel to become a full stack developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `disabled` property as a reactive property, you need to define it inside the `data` function of the component. Properties not defined in `data` are not reactive, thus vue will not pick them up when their values are changed:

```
<button :disabled="disabled" @click="whenclick">TEST</button>
    
data() {
  return {
    disabled: false
  }
},
methods: {
  whenclick(){
    this.disabled = true;
  },
},
```

To learn vue, you should really learn it from the vue docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Once you are comfortable with vue, then you should move on to laravel, since these are different tools.

Comment: Ahhh yess, it worked  i got it, I am proficient in Laravel, just wanted to go in full stack mode by learning vue js, could have more job opportunities

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the expression `false` to the `disabled` attribute. This will always be `false` and never change. You want to bind the expression `disabled`, because that refers to your `this.disabled` property:

```
:disabled="disabled"
```

This binds the `<button>`'s `disabled` attribute (`:disabled`) to your component's `disabled` property.